# dynamic radiobutton in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.radiobuttonlist

I am using `razor` view engine and having a bit of trouble creating a list of `radiobutton`.

I am populating a table with a `for` loop with the values of my model in my view.
at each row I want to have a `radiobutton`. I want to be able to select just one row and get the related items id from the model and submit it to another page. I know how to post. I actually achieved this by using `checkbox`. But the problem with `checkbox` is that it allows multiple selection.

So I guess I need to use `radiobutton`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just use JQuery to allow one Checkbox can be selected at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a ViewModel like this

```
public Class CheckOutViewModel
{
  public string SelectedPaymentType { set; get; }
  public IEnumerable<SelectItems> PaymentTypes { set; get; }
}
```

And you are setting the PaymentTypes Collection in your `GET` Action method and sending it to the view which is strongly typed to `CheckOutViewModel`

```
public ActionResult Checkout()
{
  var vm=new CheckOutViewModel
  vm.PaymentTypes=GetPaymentTypes(); //gets a list of SelectItems
  return View(vm);
}
```

And in your View

```
@model CheckOutViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  foreach (var paymentItem in Model.PaymentTypes)
  {
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(mbox => mbox.SelectedPaymentType, 
                                              paymentItem.ID.ToString())       
    @paymentItem.Name    
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Assuming `GetPaymentTypes()` method will return a list of `SelectItems` for your records in the database.

This will give you the Radio buttons with the same name value(SelectedPaymentType). so only one can be selected.

In your `POST` action, you can read the selected value by checking the SelectedPaymentType property value

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Checkout(CheckOutViewModel model)
{
  //check the value of model.SelectedPaymentType

}
```