# Edit operation bring up values from Database on Radio button

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC application to show Weekly task for each Student in a Student club. It has 2 different .cshtml one for Display values from database (Index.cshtml) and another to Edit values and save to SQL server Database (Edit.cshtml)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DaysOftheWeek](
    [DayName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ShortWeekName] [varchar](10) NULL
,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DayName] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ShortWeekName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DaysOftheWeek](DayName,ShortWeekName) Values('S','Sunday')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DaysOftheWeek](DayName,ShortWeekName) Values('M','Monday')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DaysOftheWeek](DayName,ShortWeekName) Values('T','Tuesday')

Create Table dbo.StudentTasks(StudentID INT NOT NULL,DayAssigned Char(2) null, StudentMajor VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE dbo.StudentTasks  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_day] FOREIGN KEY([DayAssigned])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DaysOftheWeek] ([ShortWeekName])
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.StudentTasks CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_day]
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentTasks(StudentID,DayAssigned,StudentMajor) Values (1,'M','Accounts')
INSERT INTO dbo.StudentTasks(StudentID,DayAssigned,StudentMajor) Values(2,'T','Math')
```

I am able to bring up the values in Index.cshtml using Entity Data Model/Controller and View.
I am having issues with Edit.

This is part of my Edit.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DayAssigned, htmlAttributes: new { @class = ".col-form-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">

                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.DayAssigned, "S") Sunday
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.DayAssigned, "M") Monday
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.DayAssigned, "T") Tuesday
                </div>
            </div>
```

I do not know how to populate Radiobutton using values from Database.
Thanks for help
MR

Comment: Are you want to return selected value from `RadioButtonFor`? What thing doesn't work? You can try check this issue for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828005/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-populate-list-of-radio-buttons-from-database.